# getting the scons root directory

Tags: scons

I need to run two programs in sequence as part of a custom builder.

One of them is a program that I'm stuck with and can't deal with absolute/relative paths so I have to use the `chdir=1` option of the Builder so that its actions run in the same directory as the target.

The second is a script that is located in the `tools` subdirectory of the project; the SConstruct file is in the root of the project. I need to create an action to run this script, and am having trouble because I have neither the absolute path to the project, nor a relative path from the directory in which the target is located back up to the `tools` subdirectory where the script is located. If I could somehow get the absolute path to the root directory of my project, I'd be all set, I could just concatenate `tools/myscript.bar' and be done with it.

Here's what I have, more or less:

```
env['BUILDERS']['FooBar'] = Builder(action = [
    'c:/bin/foo.exe ${SOURCE.filebase}',
    'c:/bin/bar-interpreter.exe myscript.bar ${SOURCE.filebase}',
    ], chdir=1);
```

The problem is that I need to change the action in question so that "myscript.bar" can be found, something like:

```
env['BUILDERS']['FooBar'] = Builder(action = [
    'c:/bin/foo.exe ${SOURCE.filebase}',
    'c:/bin/bar-interpreter.exe $PATHTOHERE/tools/myscript.bar ${SOURCE.filebase}',
    ], chdir=1);
```

This seems so simple but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grrr. It is simple; this seems to work.

```
env['BUILD_ROOT'] = Dir('.');
Builder(action = ['somecmd ${BUILD_ROOT.abspath}/tools/myscript.bar ...']);
```

Answer (score 19):

You should use "#" to indicate the top of the source directory.

```
print Dir('#').abspath
```

This version works if you use a [variant directory](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/c3271.html) too. For example in **SConstruct**:

```
SConscript('main.scons', variant_dir="build")
```

Then in **main.scons**:

```
print Dir('.').abspath
print Dir('#').abspath
```

The first will print `/path/to/project/build`, whereas the second will show the correct `/path/to/project`.