# define path to SConstruct root

Tags: scons

My folder structure is:

```
\gitclone\SConstruct
\gitclone\level1\level2\SConscript.3dn
```

Now in `SConscript.3dn` I am creating empty folder: `e.Execute(Mkdir('#/testDir'))`

How to define the file path to create the folder in `\gitclone\` (where root `SConstruct` file is)? I was reading [manual](https://scons.org/doc/2.5.0/HTML/scons-man.html), but somehow I can not manage it.

Comment: If you're using that old an SCons version, then fine, else please refer to more recent versions of doc. Usually the "production" link is better than a version-specific one, as in https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461774/getting-the-scons-root-directory), so my code is:

```
e['SCONS_ROOT'] = Dir('#')
e.Execute(Mkdir('${SCONS_ROOT.abspath}/win_b64/code/bin/testDir'))
```

Comment: You don't need to do the extra step in order to get the root evaluated, you can do that inline, as in: `e.Execute(Mkdir(Dir('#/testDir')))`